# Tool to visualize the structure of jsp:s in a web application

Tags: jsp, uml, modeling, object-model

im looking for a tool to automatically visualize (display some kind of object graph) the structure of a java web application which is built with  jsp:s and jspf:s, if there is any? I have been googling for it but can only find analysis tools for pure java classes but not for jsps. The reason I want this is to make the structure visible for the client so he can see what possibly might be affected when certain files have changed.

Suggestions for good modelling tools are also welcome if I have to do it manually.

Cheers
Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

[Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) is an excellent modelling tool with plenty of Java support, including binary reverse-engineering and automatic generation of sequence diagrams from running code. It can also be used to model web services using WSDL.

However, it does not have specific JSP support.